# Jquery Validation not working inside Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am popping up a JQuery dialog which has a form inside.

```
<div class="addcalevent">
    <form name="caleventform" id="caleventform" method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtcaltitle" name="title"  />
        </div>
       <button id="savecalevent"  >save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

When i popup the dialog, i am initializing the Jquery validation plugin.

```
    $(".addcalevent").dialog(
    {
        height: 300,
        width: 546
    }
    );
 $('#caleventform').validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            title: {
                required: "pls enter user name"
            }
        }
    });
```

Ob button click .valid() always returns true.

```
$('.addcalevent').on('click', "#savecalevent", function (event) {
    if (!$('#caleventform').valid()) {
        return;
    }
});
```

What am i doing wrong ? I am using Jquery version 1.10.2 and Validate version 1.11.0,
Does the validation works only with a "Submit" button ?

Thanks !

Comment: link the plugin please

Comment: use return false; not return.

Comment: This what i am using for plugin..    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: @Bhadra .valid is always returning true when i evaluate. One thing i just noticed, when i put required="required"  in the html, .valid() is working !

Comment: Putting the HTML validation attribute `required="required"` into your code should have absolutely no effect since you already have the `required` rule properly declared within the `.validate()` method.  I have no idea how you're examining `.valid()` but it's working fine for me here:  http://jsfiddle.net/g65g6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put your code into a jsFiddle and it clearly shows that `.valid()` working properly.  It returns `false` when there are errors and `true` when the form is valid.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/g65g6/**

---

However, you should use the `submitHandler` callback function whenever you want to do something after clicking the button of a valid form.  Use the `invalidHandler` callback to do something when the form is not valid.  Use the `.valid()` method within a `click` handler for special cases where the button is not recognized as a `submit` button, or for programatically triggering/checking validity.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".addcalevent").dialog({
        height: 300,
        width: 546
    });

    $('#caleventform').validate({
        rules: {
            title: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            title: {
                required: "pls enter user name"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // optional callback
            // fires on button click when form is valid
            // do any ajax here
            return false;
        },
        invalidHandler: function() { // optional callback
            // fires on button click when form is not valid
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/g65g6/1/**

[Documentation for all callback functions and options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do things when the form is valid, use the `submitHandler` option of Validate.

```
$("#caleventform").validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        console.log('successful submit');
        $('.addcalevent').dialog('close');
        return false;
    }
});
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/N5kjc/